# What is CvBlobTrackerAuto class in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to understand blobtrack.cpp code provided as a sample code with OpenCV. In this code class named CvBlobTrackerAuto is used. I tried to find some [documentation](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/class_cv_blob_tracker_auto.html#ab11df58e70c82ebfe3fb342bdbbe95f5) about this class but it does not provide a detailed explanation.

I am particularly interested in 
`CvBlobTrackerAuto::Process(IplImage *pImg, IplImage *pMask = NULL)` function. What does this do and what is the task of this mask used here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When I asked this question on OpenCV mailing group I was directed to following link. This document explains OpenCV Blobtracker and its modules https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/490/trunk/opencv/doc/vidsurv/Blob_Tracking_Modules.doc Hope this will be helpful to anyone studying blobtracker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been working with `CvBlobTrackerAuto` in the last few weeks. Here are some of things I have figured out.

`CvBlobTrackerAuto::Process` is used to process the last captured image in order to update the tracking information (blob ids and positions). Actually, `CvBlobTrackerAuto` is an abstract class since it doesn't provide an implementation for `CvBlobTrackerAuto::Process`. The only concrete implementation there is (as far as I can tell) is `CvBlobTrackerAuto1`, which can be found in blobtrackingauto.cpp.

What `CvBlobTrackerAuto1::Process` does is to implement the following pipeline:

- Foreground detection: this produces a binary mask corresponding to the foreground.
- Blob tracking: updates the position of blobs. It may use mean shift, particle filters or a combination of these.
- Post processing: (I'm not sure of what this section does).
- Blob deletion: it is "experimental and simple" according to a comment in there. It deletes blobs which have been too small or near the image borders in the last frames.
- Blob detection: detects new blobs. See enteringblobdetection.cpp.
- Trajectory generation: (not sure of what it does).
- Track analysis: (not sure of what it does. But I do remember having read the code and deciding that it had no influence on blob tracking, so I disabled it.)

In this particular implementation of `CvBlobTrackerAuto::Process`, the `pMask` parameter is used for nothing at all. It has a default value of NULL and it is assigned to a variable once, only to be overwritten some lines later.

The OpenCv sample to be found in samples/c/blobtrack_sample.cpp is built around this `CvBlobTrackerAuto1` class, providing different options to each module in the pipeline.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for very well detailed answer and extra info

Answer (score 1):

I was directed to this link when I posted the same question in OpenCV mailing group. [This doc](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/490/trunk/opencv/doc/vidsurv/Blob_Tracking_Modules.doc) explains OpenCV Blobtracker and its modules.
Hope this helps anyone interested.

Comment: The link you gave above asks a username and password for connectiong to svn. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Horizon1710 It seems they have moved the file to a different location. Updated the link to the new location